# Lower and upper bound of finding the max element of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What are the lower and upper bounds of finding the max number of a set of n?

is the lower bound O(1) as the best case and the upper bound is O(n-1) as the worst case?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation. For example, if you organized the elements in the form of a binary search tree, the height of the tree would be $\log_2 n$, and so the complexity would be $O(\log_2 n)$. However, if you placed the numbers in a more traditional linear array, the complexity would be $O(n)$, as all elements need to be read before you can determine the maximum. One way to determine the maximum would be to read all the elements, continuously comparing each element to a variable storing the current maximum. The content of the variable only changes if the element read is larger than the maximum. Finally, the content of the variable is output at the end of the search.

Comment: yes if finding the max value only depends on comparing values in an array, so the lower and upper bounds I've mentioned are correct?

Comment: All the values need to be read at some point, so unless you do some pre-preprocessing beforehand (for example, place them all in a sorted array), then reading it off would take $O(1)$. However, the pre-processing will certainly take more than $O(1)$ time. So, the complexity is at least $O(n)$, not $O(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer is somewhat correct. The lower limit is $\Omega(1)$ and upper limit is $O(n)$.

If you specifically use sets, then I dont't see any other way of solving the problem than linearly iterating through all elements, which has the time complexity $O(n)$.
Of course, you can insert the elements into a list and sort the list (you can not, per definition of sets, sort a set) giving you an overall time complexity of $O(nlog(n))$ ($nlog(n)$ sorting the list and $O(1)$ finding the max element).